# ShaprePoint 2016 - OOB “Upload completed” Refresh Link Broken

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, development

When the refresh button is clicked, a pound sign is added to the URL, however if I right click and select “Open link in new tab” the page will open in a new tab.

This is an OOB feature, is there a way to fix or disable this completely?

https://imgur.com/gallery/orCdrUh?s=sms

Comment: I think you need to clarify which feature of the two described you want to disable and why.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Edit the web part and change the list view layout from explorer view to all documents.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064766/shaprepoint-2016-oob-upload-completed-refresh-link-broken